# GeoJson structure

Tags: geojson, mongodb, database-design

***I currently designing a table/document database structure*** and use `GeoJson` to store points and routes. Currently I choose MongoDb, I will consider PostGIS later.

I want to store `route` info for public bus. The route contain 2 `sub routes` going back and forth in circular within the same route number. The route info contain related bus stops and waypoints.

The structure should be based on how I can query back.

**So my use case is I want to query and get the whole route info and also the current sub route based on current location.**

Which one is suitable to query from db if I structure like:

1. Use `MultiLineString` to store the 2 `LineString`s consist of bus stops and waypoints. The other info store in different column/property. Problem: How to query or differentiate sub routes.
2. Separate the sub routes in another table/document or use different column/property in a table/document (multiple geospartial indexes). Problem: Duplicate bus stops and waypoints and getting the whole route info. Probably need multiple db queries.
3. Use `Feature` in `GeoJson`. However I can't imagine how `FeatureCollection` with multiple `geometries` can help to query my use case above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to try to substitute some terms because you are using a similar word to describe two distinct ideas.  Let me know if this is wrong.

---

What I propose is going to be closest to you #2 solution:

In your data have a bus *route* that is made of one or many *leg(s)*.  We cannot have a *route* without at least one *leg*.  The *route* doesn't need to be a `MultiLineFeature` or even a spatial primitive, the job of the *route* is just to hold administrative information about itself and doesn't necessarily know anything about its *leg(s)*.

A *leg* knows which *route* (foreign key) it belongs to.  If your *legs* are pre-baked, line features then they can be your smallest needed unit.  If your *legs* are not prebaked then they can hold just information about the *leg* itself and need not to be a spatial primitive, can refer to *waypoint* to determine their shape.

Finally, there are *waypoints*, and only *waypoints*.  Stations become *waypoints*.  Why?  There is really no difference between a waypoint and a station other than one gets stopped at, to load and unload passengers, that is information that can be stored in the entry for the waypoint (eg. a field called *is_station* with a value 1 if the bus needs to stop, 0 if doesn't stop).  If *waypoints* are your smallest unit then you can update routing without having to create new line features, just update your leg/waypoint association table with new *waypoints*.

I personally would go the way of making *waypoints* my smallest unit, because it gives the greatest flexibility.

I would also make a many-to-many join collection/table.  Because a waypoint/station may also serve more than one leg, and a leg will have to have more than one waypoint.  Additionally, provide a field to give waypoints an order, that way the direction of travel can be known.

**Schema:**

```
+----------+       +--------+     +-------------+
|          |       |        |     |             |
|  ROUTES  +-1---N-+  LEGS  |     |  WAYPOINTS  |
|          |       |        |     |             |
+----------+       +----+---+     +---------+---+
                        |                   |
                        1                   1
                        |                   |
                        N                   N
                        |                   |
                   +----+-------------------+-----+
                   |   LEG/WAYPOINT ASSOCIATION   |
                   |                              |
                   +------------------------------+
```

---

**Query:**

Many public transit systems only pick people up at stations, so I would use a spatial query to find the nearest *waypoint* to my location that is `is_station=1`.

Once my station has been selected, than I perform a query that looks at a `leg/waypoint association` collection to perform a many-to-many join.  This will tell me which legs service this station.

The legs, in turn, will know which routes they serve and therefore you can know everything you need to know about your routes.  If a user is looking at your information it is up to them to decide which route they prefer, or for you to ask more information to show the optimal route.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I went to the same way, solution #2. Now I got `routes`, `points` and `waypoints` collections. `routes` store `route.stops` a sorted array of bus stop Id from `points` collection. I can then index and maintain unique and query nearby bus stop. `waypoints` collection store documents with (break into) a single `Point` location together with `routeId` so that I can query nearby route. I use `Point` instead of `MultiPoint` or `LineString` to get a single point distance and coordinate during `$geoNear` aggregate.

Comment: Great!  Trying to fill in our huge unanswered backlog where I feel ever remotely qualified to help.